# Compute the product of current row column value and previous row computed column value

Tags: sql

Below is the data set and the kind of computation i need to do using SQL

```
ID   Postdate   Return   LinkedValue
------------------------------
1001 7/1/2013   100      100
1001 7/2/2013   101      101
1001 7/3/2013   102      102*101/100
1001 7/4/2013   103      103*102*100/100
```

The LinkedValue for the very first row will be equal to the return value, but for each successive row after that it will be the product of return of current row and LinkedValue computed for previous row.

Is there a way in SQL to accomplish this?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Should be quite easy with a custom aggregate as a window function. How do you define the order of the rows? In a relational database there is no such thing as "the first row" unless you have something to `order by`. Is the order of the rows in your example defined by the `postdate` column? Or a different column?

Comment: The example is not clear. May be LinkedValues are 100, 10100, 1030200, 106110600?

Comment: Also: why isn't the last linkedvalue not  `103*102*101/100`?

Comment: The row number is defined based on the post date earliest post date will have the lowest rownumber which is auto incrementing number in Database. The database used is SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
WITH    cte_prep
          AS (
               SELECT
                    [rowid]
                ,   [ID]
                ,   [Postdate]
                ,   [Return]
                ,   RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Postdate ) AS P_Rank
                FROM
                    [meta].[dbo].[return]
             ),
        cte_recursive ( ID, Postdate, [Return], P_Rank, preturn, string, Level )
          AS (
               -- Anchor member definition
    SELECT
            e.ID
        ,   e.Postdate
        ,   e.[Return]
        ,   e.P_Rank
        ,   10 AS preturn
        ,   CAST(e.[return] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS string
        ,   0 AS Level
        FROM
            cte_prep AS e
        WHERE
            e.P_Rank = 1
               UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
               SELECT
                    e.ID
                ,   e.Postdate
                ,   e.[Return]
                ,   e.P_Rank
                ,   d.[return] AS preturn
                ,   CAST(d.string + ' * ' + CAST(e.[return] AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS string
                ,   Level + 1 AS Level
                FROM
                    cte_prep AS e
                INNER JOIN cte_recursive AS d
                ON  e.ID = d.ID AND
                    e.P_rank = d.P_rank + 1
             )
    SELECT
            *
        FROM
            cte_recursive
```

[The results look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6T2h.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple using an aggregate that multiplies as a window function.

You didn't specify your DBMS, so the following is for PostgreSQL.

Create the test table:

```
create table adi (id integer, postdate date, return integer);

insert into adi (id, postdate, return)
   values 
(1001, date '2013-07-01', 100),
(1001, date '2013-07-02', 101),
(1001, date '2013-07-03', 102),
(1001, date '2013-07-04', 103);
```

Create an aggregate that multiplies all values:

```
create aggregate mult(bigint) 
(
  sfunc = int8mul, 
  stype=bigint 
);
```

We need a result that numbers the rows and retains the `return` value of the first row. This can be done using window functions:

```
select id, 
       postdate, 
       return,
       row_number() over (order by postdate) as rn,
       first_value(return) over (order by postdate) as base_value
from adi
```

With this result we can create the final query:

```
with numbered as (
  select id, 
         postdate, 
         return,
         row_number() over (order by postdate) as rn,
         first_value(return) over (order by postdate) as base_value
  from adi
)
-- only get the first row, so that the return value of that
-- is not included in the running aggregate
select id, 
       postdate, 
       return,
       return as linkedvalue
from numbered
where rn = 1

union all

select id, 
       postdate, 
       return,
       (mult(return) over (order by postdate))::numeric / (case when rn > 2 then base_value else 1 end)
from numbered
where rn > 1;
```

This returns the following result:

```
id   | postdate   | return | linkedvalue
-----+------------+--------+------------
1001 | 2013-07-01 |    100 |         100
1001 | 2013-07-02 |    101 |      101.00
1001 | 2013-07-03 |    102 |      103.02
1001 | 2013-07-04 |    103 |    10611.06
```

---

The query is pretty much standard ANSI SQL except for the custom aggregate function. How you define one for the DBMS you are using depends on that DBMS.

Without the ability to create a custom aggregate, this can be done using a recursive CTE. The following is standard ANSI SQL without any product specific syntax:

```
with recursive numbered as (
  select id, 
         postdate, 
         return,
         row_number() over (order by postdate) as rn,
         first_value(return) over (order by postdate) as base_value
  from adi
), calc as (
  select id, postdate, return, return as linkedvalue, base_value, rn
  from numbered
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select c.id, c.postdate, c.return, 
         case when c.rn > 2 then (c.return * p.linkedvalue) else c.return end,
         p.base_value, 
         c.rn
  from numbered c
    join calc p on c.rn - 1 = p.rn
  where c.rn > 1
)
select id, postdate, return, 
       case when 
           rn > 2 then cast(linkedvalue as numeric) / 100 
           else linkedvalue 
       end as linkedvalue
from calc
order by postdate;
```